# Viewing databases values using FindAll() Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I am trying to get all values from database Find($id) works but when i try to use FindAll() it shows me following error.
Although exit(\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($questions)) this command generates all values from database .
My error is when i run the program it shows me
Key "question" for array with keys "0, 1, 2, 3" does not exist in AcmeABundle:Default:view.html.twig

**My view.html.twig file**

```
    {% extends 'AcmeABundle:Default:index.html.twig' %}
     {% block content %}
     <ul>
          {% for quiz_table in questions %}
     <li>   {{ questions.question }}
            {{ questions.choice1 }}
            {{ questions.choice2 }}
            {{ questions.choice3 }} 
            {{ questions.answer }}
</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </div>
     {% endblock %}
```

**My Controller**

```
public function showAction()
{
$repository=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeQuizBundle:QuizTable');
$questions=$repository->findAll();

  return $this->render('AcmeQuizBundle:Default:view.html.twig',array(
        'questions'=>$questions
    )

);
}
```

Comment: My error is when i run the program it shows me Key "question" for array with keys "0, 1, 2, 3" does not exist in AcmeABundle:Default:view.html.twig

Answer (score 1):

you need to loop over all items

for
Loop over each item in a sequence. For example, to display a list of users provided in a variable called users:

```
<h1>Users</h1>
<ul>
    {% for user in users %}
        <li>{{ user.username|e }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html

Comment: i have added the loop

Comment: It needs to be like this : 
    `{% for quiz_table in questions %}

        {{ quiz_table.question }}

        {{ quizz_table.choice1 }}

        {{ quizz_table.choice2 }}

        {{ quizz_table.choice3 }} 

        {{ quizz_table.answer }}

    {% endfor %}`